# Excel VBA highlight cell where Rows and Column Match with 2 sheets

Tags: excel, vba, loops, match

[Sheets which i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omirm.jpg)

Hi All, I have two columns in sheet1 with multiple rows and the same columns in sheet2 but in sheet2 values of 2nd column becomes column headings, I want to highlight the cell in sheet2 where values match from sheet1. Thanks in advance, i hope it makes clear. Screenshots also attached. i write the following code but this is not working correctly. Thanks for you help

```
Public Sub test3()

Dim rng As Range
Dim aNumber As Range
Dim bNumber As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim iRow As Long
Dim iCol As Long
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2:B" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
LastColumn = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("D1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
Set rng2 = Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(1, LastColumn))
'MsgBox rng2.Address
For iRow = 2 To 6 'this i need last row count
For iCol = 2 To 6 ''this i need last row count
    Set aNumber = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iRow, 1) 'Row, Column Searching A
    Set bNumber = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(iCol, 2) 'Row, Column Searching B

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng, aNumber) > 0 Then
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rng2, bNumber) > 0 Then

        ColNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(bNumber, rng2, 0)
        RowNum = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(aNumber, rng, 0)
        'MsgBox (RowNum + 1)
        'MsgBox (ColNum)
        Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(RowNum + 1, ColNum).Interior.Color = vbGreen
    Else
        'MsgBox aNumber & " does not exist in range " & rng.Address
    End If
    End If
Next iCol
Next iRow
End Sub
```

Comment: In your first table, is the second row supposed to be `Language 2 | Jave`? Or indeed `Language 1 | Jave`?

Comment: ** Language 1 Java, Rows can be duplicate but if you want unique values when combining we can add 3rd column also

Comment: Create two named ranges on your `Sheet1`, the first for the `Language 1`, `Language 2`, etc list (I named it `listLanguageHeaderA` and the second for the the `Java`, `Jave`, etc list (I named it `listLanguageHeaderB`).  Then use this conditional format formula in cell B2 on `Sheet2`: `=COUNTIFS(listLanguageHeaderA,$A2,listLanguageHeaderB,B$1)>0` and apply the conditional formatting to range: `=$B$2:$G$7`

Comment: ...or you could do that @tigeravatar :P

Answer (score 1):

With a helper column C (`=CONCAT($A2,$B2)`), you can do this with Conditional Formatting.

Set up your helper column:

[image]

Then, set up a new Conditional Formatting rule.

Rule:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($C$3:$C$8,MATCH(CONCAT($E3,F$2),$C$3:$C$8,0))),FALSE,TRUE)
```

Applies To Range:

```
=$F$3:$K$8
```

You may have to tweak those ranges, but that worked for me:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bruce for your help, it's working. Is it possible that if the some cells are already highlighted with blue then I don't wana apply formatting on these cells?

Comment: @Dani what makes them hilighted blue (meaning the logic as to why)?

Comment: Those are manually highlighted as blue no logic for blue I mean if cells already highlighted blue then dont apply formating on those cells

Comment: You can say if course discontinued then highlight with blue but we don't want add column for disconnected course

Comment: I have 2 excel sheets. Sheet 1 have following records:

Salon          coach       date         amount
Sal1           col1       11/7/2018     500
Sal1           col1       11/1/2018     400
Sal1           col1       10/25/2018    600
Sal1           col1       10/19/2018    700
Sal1           col1       10/1/2018     250
And so on
Sheet 2 have following cloumns and records:

Salon     coach       average of lastest 4 dates
Sal1          col1                       ???
I want to find average amount for 4 latest dates with match the criteria salon and coach. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Dani - Does that have to do with this question? That sounds like a new one altogether.

Comment: Yes i posted as new question but no one replied so i also asked here, i thought you will reply

Comment: can you help regarding this question